# Remote control receiver for robot control

Tags: java, linux, networking, raspberry-pi

I have built an RC car and attached a Raspberry Pi to it - in order to control it, I wrote some Java code to listen to commands over the network and make the car move accordingly.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;

 public class Reciever {  // note that Receiver is misspelled in this line and throughout the code

    static Process p;
    static PrintWriter out;
    static BufferedReader input;
    static BufferedReader error;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] ex = {
            "/bin/sh", "-c", "bash"
        };
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ex);

            out = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                out.println("gpio mode " + i + " out");
            }
            input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            error = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("GPIOs setup");

        new Network();
    }

 }
```

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Network {

    private static ClientListener clientListener;
    private static Thread clientListenerThread;

    Network() {
        clientListener = new ClientListener();
        clientListenerThread = new Thread(clientListener);
        clientListenerThread.start();
    }

    class ClientListener implements Runnable {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        ClientListener() {}

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
                System.out.println("running network listener");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (true) {
                try {
                    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    new Thread(new Controller(clientSocket)).start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //  e.printStackTrace();  // so timeout errors
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Controller implements Runnable {
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader in ;

    public Controller(Socket clientSocket) {
        s = clientSocket;
        try { in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()));

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!s.isClosed()) {
            String m = "";
            try {
                while ((m = in .readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("recieved " + m);
                    switch (m) {
                        case "f":
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 1 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 2 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 3 0");
                            System.out.println("set pins to forward");
                            break;
                        case "b":
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 1 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 2 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 3 1");
                            break;
                        case "l":
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 1 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 2 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 3 0");
                            break;
                        case "r":
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 1");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 1 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 2 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 3 1");
                            break;
                        case "s":
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 1 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 2 0");
                            Reciever.out.println("gpio write 3 0");
                            break;
                    }
                    Reciever.out.flush();

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static Socket s;
    static PrintWriter output;
    static InputStream input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "192.168.123.14";
        try {
            s = new Socket(url, 9090);
            output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            s.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);
            input = s.getInputStream();
            new Thread(new Writer(s)).start();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
            String consoleInput = "";

            while (!s.isClosed()) {
                consoleInput = in .nextLine();
                output.write(consoleInput + '\n');
                output.flush();
                System.out.println("sent " + consoleInput);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static class Writer implements Runnable {
        String str;
        Socket sock;
        BufferedReader input;

        public Writer(Socket s) {
            sock = s;
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while ((str = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {};

        }
    }

}
```

To control it, it receives the messages "f" (forward), "b" (backwards), "r" (right), "l" (left), and "s" (stop), and sets the GPIO pins that control the electric motors accordingly (it has two motors, one on that controls the left wheels (pins 0 and 1) and one that controls the right wheels (pins 2 and 3)

It relies on the [wiring Pi utility](http://wiringpi.com/) for controlling the GPIO pins, and communicates with it via a shell environment. There isn't much of a practical point for writing it in Java (and having to deal with the shell stuff vs importing a library in C for the functions), but the next part is to write an android app that will send the relevant messages, and since that would be written in Java, I felt like writing this in Java as well (not that there couldn't be inter-language communication over the network..)

At some point I might like to move to a Bluetooth communication instead, so that it doesn't rely on the two devices being on the same LAN.

Although it works as-is right now, there seems to be a leak of some sort as it gradually becomes less responsive (not sure of if it's over time or over lots of commands), but the quick & dirty way of fixing it was to just re-launch it via crontab on the Pi every so often.

I don't know of a good way for testing this outside of on a raspberry pi with the "wiring pi" utility installed, as the outputs are physical pins turning on and off.

Comment: This sounds like a fun/awesome project. I hope you get some fine answers.

Comment: You misspelled the title

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel fixed the title, but it seems I misspelled it all over my code as well.. time for a re-factor!

Comment: @user2813274 You should warn the other users about it

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel added a comment in the original code explaining it

Comment: That's not what I meant. The review you have has it misspeled. You can simply fix it in your code and comment on @SirPython's answer for him to be aware of this and fix his answer as well.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel not sure I should change the code, as the intent was for it to be posted with all it's flaws and remain so - why should I fix a typo but not other fixes? And while I could fix it, I don't see much benefit - there is a comment for anyone who cares already, and it's not like anyone should just copy-paste the code without even reading the comments/SirPython's review (and especially not if they expect "good" code)

Comment: @user2813274 SirPython copied without looking at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25584/discussion-between-user2813274-and-ismael-miguel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the properties of your classes are missing scope identifiers.

For example, these properties of `Receiver`

```
static Process p;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader input;
static BufferedReader error;
```

should have scope identifiers. Judging by your use for these properties, I'd say you should give `out` a `public` modifier, and the rest `private` modifiers.

---

Instead of giving the messages single letter string names, I recommend creating an enumerated type that stores the types of messages.

Here is what I came up with:

```
public enum MOVEMENT {
    FORWARD([1,0,1,0]), 
    BACKWARD([0,1,0,1]),
    RIGHT([1,0,0,1]), 
    LEFT([0,1,1,0]), 
    STOP([0,0,0,0])

    public final int[] signal;
    private MOVEMENT(signal) {
        this.signal = signal;
    }

}
```

Notice something about `signal`? The 4 numbers in signal are the second number of the 4 times you are logging to `Reciever`. I didn't include the first number since the first number was the same for each option.

Now, to further simplify the switch statement, we are going to want to create a function that sends the 4 signals over to `Reciever` that uses our new enum.

Here is what I came up with:

```
private void sendToReciever(MOVEMENT movement) {
    for(int i = 0; i < movement.signal.length; i++) {
        Reciever.out.println("gpio write 0 " + movement.signal[i]);
    }
}
```

Now, your switch statement becomes:

```
switch (m) {
    case "f":
        sendToReciever(MOVEMENT.FORWARD);
        break;
    case "b":
        sendToReciever(MOVEMENT.BACKWARDS);
        break;
    case "l":
        sendToReciever(MOVEMENT.LEFT);
        break;
    case "r":
        sendToReciever(MOVEMENT.RIGHT);
        break;
    case "s":
        sendToReciever(MOVEMENT.STOP);
        break;
}
```

---

From `.run` of `ClientListener` of `Network`:

```
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9090);
    System.out.println("running network listener");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
while (true) {
```

1. You shouldn't just be catching exception.

Catch a more specific exception. Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)) for `ServerSocket`, the exception that would be raised for how you are opening up the `ServerSocket` would be an `IOException`.

2. You should exit the function.

If there was some sort of error while making `ServerSocket`, the rest of your code isn't going to work. At this point, you just exit the function and return something like -1 to symoblize an error.

---

Add JavaDoc to your functions and classes.

---

```
try {
    serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    new Thread(new Controller(clientSocket)).start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //  e.printStackTrace();  // so timeout errors
}
```

1. You should move `serverSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);` outside of the `try` statement because you don't need to redefine the timeout time every loop.
2. There are two kinds of errors that could happen here: a timeout error, and an `IOException` from `serverSocket.accept`.

---

My guess on why this gets sluggish is because you have an infinite loop in `Network` that creates a new thread every loop.

Comment: Any ideas as to why it would become sluggish after a while?

Comment: @user2813274 I edited my answer to include more information.

Comment: Ah, that seems like an obvious reason that I missed, thanks!